# immutable react reducer state is not updating

Tags: reactjs, redux, immutable.js

I am trying to create a simple website using react-redux and the immutable-assign library (instead of immutable) to handle my state. (documentation for immutable-assign: https://github.com/engineforce/ImmutableAssign)

I've made solutions with both the 'immutable' and 'immutable-assign' libraries, but neither work (code for immutable solution is commented out in the reducer below. No matter which changes I make, the state never changes, and the values are never assigned to `menuItems`

The `setMenu(newMenu)` function is currently called with dummydata in the form of a list of arrays in the following format:

```
menuItems: {
            id: "113",
            foodItem: "tesatewr",
            description: "gfdgsdfsdf",
            price: 999
        }
```

The reducer:

```
import { iassign } from 'immutable-assign'

export function setMenu(newMenu) {return {type: 'SET_MENU_ITEMS', newMenu}}

const initialState = {
  date: 'test', 
  menuId: 'test', 
  menuItems: []     

  }

 function menuViewReducer(state = initialState, action){
  switch(action.type){
    case 'SET_MENU_ITEMS':

      var itemList = iassign(
          state,
          function (n) { n.push('testtest'); return n}
      )

      return state.set(['menuItems'], itemList)
    default:
      return state  
  }
}

/* CODE FOR IMMUTABLE
 function menuViewReducer(state = fromJS(initialState), action){
  switch(action.type){
    case 'SET_MENU_ITEMS':
      return state.updateIn(['menuItems'], (menuItems) => menuItems.push(fromJS(action.newMenu.menuItems)))
    default:
      return state  
  }
} */


export const menuSelector = {
  date: state => state.menuViewList.date,
  menuId: state => state.menuViewList.menuId,
  menuItems: state => state.menuViewList.menuItems
}

export default menuViewReducer
```

Render function:

```
render(){
    return (
      <div>
        Test data here: {this.props.menuItems}
        <ul className="menuViewList">{ this.mapMenuItemsToListElements() }</ul>
        <button 
        onClick={() => this.mapMenuItemsToListElements()}> get data  
        </button>
      </div>

    )
  }
```

Comment: It's really hard to figure out what's not working from just this code. The problem could be with how you're connecting this reducer to your store, or how you're dispatching actions to your store, or with how you're rendering your data.

As it is, I don't think you're going to get an answer that directly solves your problem. I recommend reading [these guidelines on how to give a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error and as Simon pointed out, its hard to find from my submitted code.

I was calling setMenu(newMenu) in a generator function, so I should have called it like this:

`yield put(setMenu(newMenu))`

instead of

`setMenu(newMenu)`

Answer (score 0):

It's really hard to figure out what's not working from this code. The best I can do is give you some debugging tips:

First off, are you getting any errors? If yes, that seems like a good place to start.

Otherwise, try to narrow down where the problem is occurring.

**Are you sure your reducer is actually getting called?**
I would try putting a `console.log` right after your `case 'SET_MENU_ITEMS':` so you know when your code is being run.

**If it's not:**
The problem could be a number of things:

- Your reducer isn't connected to your store properly
- You're not properly dispatching actions to your store
- The actions you're dispatching don't have their `type` property properly set.

**If it is:**

The problem could be a number of different things. Some that I can think of:

- Your state isn't being updated (properly). Try logging the state at the start of your reducer and your new state right before you return it. Or consider using [redux-devtools](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-devtools) to inspect your state.
- Your view isn't getting updated. Maybe your component isn't connected to your store properly.